# Unresolved reference: AppCompatActivity and ActivityMainBinding

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I am trying set up a minimal project to  serve as base to future developments to work with gradle (version 7.4.2), kotlin (version 1.6.21) and vscode. I have this main activity right now:

```
package org.kleber.minimal;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import org.kleber.minimal.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import android.os.Bundle

 class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)
    }
}
```

In the editor, AppCompatActivity and ActivityMainBinding are marked as Unresolved references. When I try build the project (with `gradle assembleDebug`), I got this error:

```
e: /.../MainActivity.kt: (13, 9): None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
public open fun setContentView(p0: View!): Unit defined in org.kleber.minimal.MainActivity
public open fun setContentView(p0: Int): Unit defined in org.kleber.minimal.MainActivity
e: /.../MainActivity.kt: (13, 32): Cannot access class 'Constraintlayout'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
```

my gradle.build file (top-level) is:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.6.21"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

my gradle.build file (module) is:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 32
    buildToolsVersion "32.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.kleber.minimal"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.0-alpha01'
}
```

Anyone can tell what is wrong here? what I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

AndroidStudio can sometimes give errors like this. Can you do clean & rebuild project. (Build -> Clean Project)

If that doesn't work either, maybe doing invalidate caches & restart and try again to get the build might work (File -> Invalidate Caches)

Comment: i am not using AndroidStudio for this project.

Comment: hmm, I have no idea how can you do this in another ide